# Response.Redirect in Application_AuthenticateRequest RawUrl

Tags: asp.net, response.redirect, rawurl

I am using a Response.Redirect in global.asax.cs.
When the page loads the RawUrl property contains an encoded directory of some kind.

"/(F(D7zFAWNl_SpT-cuyRXksIZnvwBB_bYfBl3ens83McZjPg9zLBvcjvik6FkwBNhnjeK-faeUt6PUYOZSsYXKdg4hi4IDPTDO5diQf693NLpw1))/Integration/Workflow.aspx"

Where does this horrible directory come from?
It's breaking a bunch of user controls on the target page which use the RawUrl to get path information.

Why would Response.Redirect invent this horrible path and add it?
Is there any way around this?

Thanks

Craig

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"(F(D7zFAWNl_SpT-cuyRXksIZnvwBB_bYfBl3ens83McZjPg9zLBvcjvik6FkwBNhnjeK-faeUt6PUYOZSsYXKdg4hi4IDPTDO5diQf693NLpw1))" is your session id or auth. id stored in your URL and not in a cookie. You can change this in your web.config file

Answer (score 0):

It is the setting that is taken from the web.config as in the following location;

```
<authentication mode="Forms">
  <forms loginUrl="~/en/Access/Login" defaultUrl="~" cookieless="UseUri" timeout="2880" />
</authentication>
```

If you set `cookieless="UseUri"`, your session details will be appended to your URL instead of storing in a cookie.

Set `cookieless="UseCookies"` or remove the `cookieless` attribute to use cookie instead of URL for session details